# Error C2146 & C4430

Tags: c#, c++, dll, compiler-errors, static-libraries

I have a Visual Studio solution with 3 projects - 1 C# and 2 C++ projects. All projects were compiling successfully until now. Now I get the following errors when I build my Solution:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\propidl.h(327): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cal'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\propidl.h(327): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

One C++ project is a static lib and the other is a dll. The dll is dependent on the static lib. The C# application is dependent on the dll. Hence the project build order is this way:

```
Static Library --> DLL --> C# Application
```

The above errors come while building the Static Library which contains C Code. I have no clue why these errors are popping. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The errors are "popping" because there's something wrong with your code. It's impossible to say anything more specific. Are those really the *first* errors to "pop"? (If the library contains C code, why does the error message say "C++"?)

Comment: Post minimal code generating the error. Also it seems the C# and C++ tags on this question are wrong, it should be C, since the actual errors only appear in your first project the rest doesn't matter?

Comment: @molbdnilo: if you see the file in which the error is throwing, it's not my code.

Comment: Put `#undef CAL` before the #include of the windows header(s) and try again.

Comment: @Abhishek Your code is causing it, possibly because you've defined a macro named "CAL" which expands to nothing.